# Google Managed SSL Certificate use SSL v3

Tags: google-cloud-platform, https, ssl-certificate, certificate, google-kubernetes-engine

I would like to use Google Managed Certificate on GKE.

I have a GKE cluster (1.22) with the `external-dns` helm chart configured against a CloudDNS zone, then I tried:

```bash
$ gcloud compute ssl-certificates create managed-cert \
    --description "managed-cert" \
    --domains "<hostname>" \
    --global

$ kubectl create ns test

$ cat <<EOF | kubectl apply -f -
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-mc-deployment
  namespace: test
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: products
      department: sales
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: products
        department: sales
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: hello
        image: "gcr.io/google-samples/hello-app:2.0"
        env:
        - name: "PORT"
          value: "50001"

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-mc-service
  namespace: test
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: products
    department: sales
  ports:
  - name: my-first-port
    protocol: TCP
    port: 60001
    targetPort: 50001

---
apiVersion: networking.gke.io/v1
kind: ManagedCertificate
metadata:
  name: managed-cert
  namespace: test
spec:
  domains:
    - <hostname>

---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-psc-ingress
  namespace: test
  annotations:
    networking.gke.io/managed-certificates: "managed-cert"
    ingress.gcp.kubernetes.io/pre-shared-cert: "managed-cert"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "gce"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: "<hostname>"
    http:
      paths:
      - path: "/"
        pathType: "ImplementationSpecific"
        backend:
          service:
            name: "my-mc-service"
            port:
              number: 60001
EOF
```

The DNS zone is correctly updated and I am able to browse `http://<hostname>`.

Instead if I:

```bash
$ curl -v https://<hostname>
*   Trying 34.120.218.42:443...
* Connected to <hostname> (34.120.218.42) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
*  CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
*  CApath: none
* TLSv1.0 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.0 (IN), TLS header, Unknown (21):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS alert, handshake failure (552):
* error:0A000410:SSL routines::sslv3 alert handshake failure
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) error:0A000410:SSL routines::sslv3 alert handshake failure

$ gcloud compute ssl-certificates list 
NAME                                       TYPE     CREATION_TIMESTAMP             EXPIRE_TIME  MANAGED_STATUS
managed-cert                               MANAGED  2022-06-30T00:27:25.708-07:00               PROVISIONING
    <hostname>: PROVISIONING
mcrt-fe44e023-3234-42cc-b009-67f57dcdc5ef  MANAGED  2022-06-30T00:27:52.707-07:00               PROVISIONING
    <hostname>: PROVISIONING
```

I do not understand why it is creating a new managed certificate (`mcrt-fe44e023-3234-42cc-b009-67f57dcdc5ef`) even if I am specifing it.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: I don't see any indicator for SSLv3 being used. The client tries TLS but fails for an unknown reason and thus sends an alert. Check the server for TLS versions e.g. using https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ or locally https://testssl.sh/

Comment: In the above mentioned Ingress Yaml file, in annotations, you have listed  two certificates which are  mentioned as managed certificate and Pre shared certificate. Due to this, in output we can see two SSL certificates .
Refer to the link for more information on [specifying certificates for Ingress](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ingress-multi-ssl#specifying_certificates_for_your_ingress)

Comment: Yes but I am pointing to the same managed certificate. If I remove `  ingress.gcp.kubernetes.io/pre-shared-cert: "managed-cert"` another managed certificate is created (`mcrt-XXX`) anyway

Comment: The reason for the errors is caused by the certificate still being in the **PROVISIONING** state.

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of experimentation I understand what is going on.

The code above works, it takes around 20 minutes for the certificate to be created and propagated.

Regarding the double certificates: it is not required to create a `ssl-certificates` object as the `ManagedCertificate` custom resource will create it for you (`mcrt-*`).

To recap a example:

```yaml
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-mc-deployment
  namespace: test
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: products
      department: sales
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: products
        department: sales
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: hello
        image: "gcr.io/google-samples/hello-app:2.0"
        env:
        - name: "PORT"
          value: "50001"

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-mc-service
  namespace: test
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: products
    department: sales
  ports:
  - name: my-first-port
    protocol: TCP
    port: 60001
    targetPort: 50001

---
apiVersion: networking.gke.io/v1
kind: ManagedCertificate
metadata:
  name: managed-cert
  namespace: test
spec:
  domains:
    - <hostname>

---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-psc-ingress
  namespace: test
  annotations:
    networking.gke.io/managed-certificates: "managed-cert"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "gce"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: "<hostname>"
    http:
      paths:
      - path: "/"
        pathType: "ImplementationSpecific"
        backend:
          service:
            name: "my-mc-service"
            port:
              number: 60001
```